# Efficiency of electrical circuit

Tags: voltage

I am going to install 30kw solar system? Who will have nore efficiency if a use a single 30kw inverter or 3 inverters of 10kW in parallel? And which would be best combination?
Note: three 10kw can be synchronized and every unverter has an efficiency of 90%.

Comment: You are missing the crucial information of what the load is... That is what will make the decision for you.

Comment: This is dependent on so many additional information... How many strings can the inverter manage independently? Do you have partial shadowing on the solar panels? How are the panels connected?

Comment: It all pales to insignificance when you consider that a panel’s efficiency is probably around 20%.

Comment: 90% is 90%, no matter how you cut it. If the inverters' efficiencies vary with load, then you need to find that information.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking, one larger electrical machine will be cheaper and more efficient than N smaller electrical machines when running at full load.

However, there are many more considerations that might tip the balance in favour of several smaller machines. Flexibility, and efficiency at part load, you can just use one or two. Redundancy, a single failure won't take you completely offline. Installation space, you might be able to reuse small amounts of space rather than build a new room or foundation. Installation growth, spend money in smaller installments.

Specifically with solar installations, if groups of panels face in different directions, then it's more efficient to run each direction into its own MPPT inverter.